# what syntax to use to update a SET column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, enums, set

I created a column called oilcompany that has SET data (Hunt, Pioneer, Chevron, BP)

I can enter any one of those into the oilcompany column and change from one to another one but I can not figure out how to change from one oilcompany to multiple oilcompany (eg. Hunt and BP)... any suggestion?

Comment: Set to 'Hunt,BP'.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.) Additional schema
information and where your attempts failed would also help us to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

In the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set.html) there are not examples for UPDATE statements, but I normally use two ways to update these kind of columns:

- Using text values
- Using numeric values

**Creating the test environment**

```sql
mysql> CREATE TABLE tmp_table(
    ->     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    ->     oilcompany SET('Hunt', 'Pioneer', 'Chevron', 'BP')
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.54 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO tmp_table(oilcompany) VALUES ('Hunt'), ('Pioneer');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.11 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM tmp_table;
+----+------------+
| id | oilcompany |
+----+------------+
|  1 | Hunt       |
|  2 | Pioneer    |
+----+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Alternative#1: Using Text Values**

As a SET is a collection of ENUM elements, and any ENUM element can be treated as a string, then we can do things like:

```sql
mysql> UPDATE tmp_table
    -> SET    oilcompany = 'Hunt,BP'
    -> WHERE  id = 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM tmp_table;
+----+------------+
| id | oilcompany |
+----+------------+
|  1 | Hunt,BP    |
|  2 | Pioneer    |
+----+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Alternative#2: Using Numeric Values**

Any SET element is stored internally as a 64bit number containing the combination of the bits that represent each SET element. 
In our table: `'Hunt'=1, 'Pioneer'=2, 'Chevron'=4, 'BP'=8`.

Also, mysql allows to use these numbers instead of text values. If we need to see the numeric value in the select, we need to use the SET column inside a numeric expression (E.g. adding zero). 
Let's see the current values:

```sql
mysql> SELECT id, oilcompany+0, oilcompany FROM tmp_table;
+----+--------------+------------+
| id | oilcompany+0 | oilcompany |
+----+--------------+------------+
|  1 |            9 | Hunt,BP    |
|  2 |            2 | Pioneer    |
+----+--------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here `9 = 'Hunt' (1) + 'BP' (8)` and `2 = 'Pioneer' (2)`.

Now, let's change the `Pioneer` to `'Hunt' (1) + 'Chevron' (4)`:

```sql
mysql> UPDATE tmp_table
    -> SET    oilcompany = 5
    -> WHERE  id = 2;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.08 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT id, oilcompany+0, oilcompany FROM tmp_table;
+----+--------------+--------------+
| id | oilcompany+0 | oilcompany   |
+----+--------------+--------------+
|  1 |            9 | Hunt,BP      |
|  2 |            5 | Hunt,Chevron |
+----+--------------+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```